# How to update another columnfamily when a columnfamily has been updated in cassandra 3.x

Tags: java, cassandra, triggers, nosql, cassandra-3.0

Let's say there are two column families "A","B" in cassandra , If an value of a column in A is updated or row  is inserted to column A , those values/row should be also updated in the column family "B". It can also be done by materialized view , but I'm expecting triggering based solution in cassandra. I didn't find any proper document for triggers in cassandra.

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html

Comment: thanks   for the link, but I haven't got clear idea about triggers. Are there any examples ? that can be referred .

Comment: Materialized views are pretty buggy so it's better to avoid for the moment.

Comment: dont use triggers or materialized views, just insert to both tables or if really need consistency use logged batches.

Comment: Thanku , Expected a solution like logged batches.